# SharePoint 2013 Migration - Home Page Style Unusable

Tags: 2013, master-page, custom-masterpage, default-document

I have a WSS 3.0 environment that we are migrating to SP2013 and the upgrade went as planned (and somewhat expected).  We have a few sites that were apparently customized when it was WSS 2.0 and I am unable to make the default.aspx page look normal.  At this point, I do not care about customizations, I just want the page to look like SP2013 and I have tried resetting the master page and the custom master page back to default, as well as deleting the default.aspx page and copying from another site that looks normal and setting it as the home page.  This has not worked.  Apparently, the styling is coming from somewhere else.  Can someone tell me how to get the default page to look normal (I don't care about the content, just a blank page would be fine with me) or what else I can do to get this working properly?

Comment: use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg699337(v=vs.85).aspx to see where the styles are coming from

Comment: http://mysite/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css?rev=[theres a guid here].  All of the links on the page (site settings, documents and lists, create, etc. all have /1033/ in the URL which doesn't exist and I'm assuming came from the WSS 3.0 environment).  Know of a way to remove all of that?  I thought that was driven by the master page but apparently not.

Comment: try doing Site Settings -> Reset to site definition

Comment: Only problem I have with resetting to site definition, is that it will remove any custom web parts that the users have added to various pages throughout the site.  The issue I seem to be having is localized to the default.aspx page and I'm assuming it's coming from the master page (incorrect compat level).